# If P=NP, are all P problems NP-complete?

Tags: np-complete

In my understanding, if we could prove one of the NP-complete problems is a P problem, then all of the NP problems are P problems. Because P problems are NP problems and NP problems are P problems, P=NP.

I thought if P=NP, then all NP-complete problems are also P problems, but not all P problems are NP-complete.

But it seems that if P=NP, P=NP=NP-complete problems.

I wonder what my blind spot is.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/152187/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4468616/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1):

In order to be NP-complete, the problem has to be also NP-hard.
That means, there exists a polynomial-time reduction from SAT to the given problem.  The mapping has to map all satisfiable instances of SAT to YES-instances of the problem, and all unsatisfiable instances of SAT to NO-instances of the problem.  This means that, any NP-hard problem has to be nontrivial: there should be at least one YES-instance and at least one NO-instance.

On the other hand, if you think about it, that is precisely the sufficient condition to be NP-hard: if your problem has both an YES-instance and a NO-instance, then you can design a simple polynomial-time reduction from SAT: given a SAT-instance $f$, decide if $f$ is satisfiable or not in polynomial-time (possible since P=NP), and if it is satisfiable, then map it to the YES-instance, and if not, map it to the NO-instance.

So, when P=NP, all P problems are NP-complete, except those trivial problems where all answers are YES, or all answers are NO.

Answer (score 0):

AYun's right. I was confused by the "trivial" instances in P because there is no mapping from SAT to an all-yes problem.

Here is original Answer:

$NPC\subset NP$, that's your possible mistake. Do not use **equal**, because they are not equal at all.

Comment: [picture](https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.abefcd0688b70ccea4ad92cf8050a6d7?rik=8xIgF1clRk87vA&riu=http%3a%2f%2f3.bp.blogspot.com%2f_zUbnTFdqWyg%2fTGAeo1OxMmI%2fAAAAAAAAAFA%2f4MlUdwPvuAw%2fs1600%2f800px-P_np_np-complete_np-hard.svg.png&ehk=3asxGLKIf7BERx52v%2f7Rekpe1bL41uS%2bHZHE0j6pc9M%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0) I think this picture means if p=np, then p=np=np-complete?

Comment: I've understood my mistakes, you can check AYun's answer. Sorry for my wrong.